# IOException while reading synonyms_path_path (synonyms token filter)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using synonyms token filter with custom file

installed elasticsearch 6.7 as a service on windows 10 machine
my **synonyms.txt** is located at `C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\analysis\synonyms.txt`

here is my index settings

```
PUT /synonyms
{
   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
       "filter": {
         "synonym": {
           "type": "synonym",
           "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonyms.txt"
         }
       },
     "analyzer": {
       "my_analyzer": {
         "tokenizer": "standard",
         "filter": [
           "lowercase",
           "synonym"
         ]
       }
     }
     }
   },
   "mappings": {
     "_doc": {
       "properties": {
          "description": {
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I am getting this error while creating above index

```
{
   "error": {
     "root_cause": [{
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\analysis\synonyms.txt"
     }],
   "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
   "reason": "IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\analysis\synonyms.txt",
   "caused_by": {
   "type": "no_such_file_exception",
   "reason": "C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\analysis\synonyms.txt"
   }
},
"status": 400
}
```

also tried synonyms token filter in elasticsearch installed as archive distribution **.zip** on windows machine but getting same error
but in linux machine for both archive as well as package distributions it is working.

Thanks in advance. Happy searching

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure that the file is located at `C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\analysis\synonyms.txt` because `no_such_file_exception` makes me doubt that.

Comment: yes i am 100% sure

Comment: And the file has the proper rights that the ES service is allowed to read it?

Comment: and i am also able to access it with same path in windows file explorer

Comment: yes file has all rights it is set to full control for all users and groups,i don't think it has permission issues because es can access configuration files(elasticsearch.yml) from same config folder

Comment: got it , it was my fault actually file name is "synonyms.txt.txt" as extensions are set to hidden on my windows machine.changing file name solved my problem

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is the file extensions are hidden from control panel.so you can just go to control panel>file explorer options>  click on view tab there uncheck option(hide extension for known file types)
[it should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvDnD.png)
now rename your file accordingly and try again